# Rails3 + activeadmin: Filter with converted unix timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin

I need to add a filter in my ActiveAdmin resource where I can choose a time range. The problem is that the time is stored as a Unix timestamp in the database. I've managed to convert it so it gets displayed correctly in the index table.

```
Time.at(1345094274).to_time.strftime("%H:%M %Z")
```

but how can I add a filter so you can choose a certain time range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter use meta_search, so you must create custom search because your filter don't use active record column.

Maybe help you [activeadmin issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/45#issuecomment-1203792)